# Creating checkbox within a GUI

Tags: autohotkey

I created a checkbox and then a GUI. However, I want to create another checkbox within that same GUI, but it is telling me that I need to enter "return" at the BOLD section below.

If I do that, the rest of my script will stop. Basically, if the user checks YES, then I want the second GUI within that GUI. But if the user checks NO, then I want the hotkey to skip to the rest of the script (which is not included below).

How could I do that?

```
Send, {ENTER}
gui, font, s14
gui, add, checkbox, w200 y15 vyesy, YES
gui, add, checkbox, w200 vnon, NO
gui, add, button,  gfem, continue
gui, show, w200 h175, GYN EXAM?
Return

fem:
Gui, submit
Send, {space}
Sleep, 500


if non = 1
 {
 send, {space}
 }
gui, destroy
If yesy = 1
{
Send,GYN:{SPACE}
Progress, m2 b fs14 zh0, Date of LMP, , , Arial
Inputbox, LMP, LMP 
Progress, Off
Sleep, 500
Send,LMP{SPACE}%LMP%,{SPACE}
Progress, m2 b fs14 zh0, Duration`ndays wks mo  , , , Arial
Inputbox, duration, Duration 
Progress, Off
Sleep, 500
Send, Duration{SPACE}%duration%,{SPACE}
Progress, m2 b fs14 zh0, G_/P_ `nPlease include letters G&P, , , Arial
Inputbox, gp, G_/P_ 
Progress, Off
Sleep, 500
Send,%gp%{SPACE}

gui, font, s14
gui, add, checkbox, w115 y15 virreg, Irregular
gui, add, checkbox, w115 vhflow, Heavy flow
gui, add, checkbox, w115 vndys, Dysmenorrhia
gui, add, checkbox, w115 y15 x+8 vreg, Regular
gui, add, checkbox, w150 y+9 vflow, Normal flow
gui, add, checkbox, w200 y+9 vdysmenorrhia, No Dysmenorrhia
gui, Add, button, x120 y130 gGyYN, continue 
gui, Show, w400 h200, GYN
return


GYyN:
gui, Submit
SEND,{space}
Sleep, 500

if irreg = 1
 {
  send, -{space}Irregular{space}
Progress, m2 b fs14 zh0, Further details of `nirregular flow, , , Arial
Inputbox, irf, Irregular flow details
Progress, Off
Sleep, 500
Send,%irf%

 }
if hflow = 1
 {
  send, -{SPACE}Heavy flow{space}
Progress, m2 b fs14 zh0, Further details of `nheavy flow, , , Arial
Inputbox, hfl, Heavy flow details
Progress, Off
Sleep, 500
Send,%hfl%
 }
if ndys = 1
 {
  send, -{space}Dysmenorrhia{space}
Progress, m2 b fs14 zh0, Further details of `ndysmenorrhia, , , Arial
Inputbox, dysmni, Dysmenorrhia details
Progress, Off
Sleep, 500
Send,%dysmni%
  - Normal flow- No Dysmenorrhia
 }
if reg = 1
 {
  send, -{space}Regular
 }  
if flow = 1
 {
  send, -{space}Normal flow
 }
if dysmenorrhia = 1
 {
  send, -{SPACE}No Dysmenorrhia
**return**
 }}
gui, destroy
```

Comment: (Please [edit] your question if I got the language tag wrong.)

Comment: Who is telling you where to insert a return? If it is the AHK interpreter, it would be helpful if you provided the error message. Be that as it may, you usually should finish subroutines with a `return`, that is, the last command should be an **unconditional** `return`. Place the `return` two lines below its current position, right above the `gui, destroy`. Currently, the `return` is only reached if `dysmenorrhia` (I think you have a spelling mistake there) equals *1*. Also, after that same condition, there is one `}` too much.

Comment: And maybe you should give your script some kind of short description, the first impression could be rather disturbing, especially if you're not prepared...

Answer (score 0):

AHK doesn't like that you open the second GUI within the 
    If yesy = 1
block. If you write it like this the error goes away.

```
Send, {ENTER}
gui, font, s14
gui, add, checkbox, w200 y15 vyesy, YES
gui, add, checkbox, w200 vnon, NO
gui, add, button,  gfem, continue
gui, show, w200 h175, GYN EXAM?
Return

fem:
Gui, submit
Send, {space}
Sleep, 500

gui, destroy

if non = 1
 {
 send, {space}
 }

If yesy <> 1
  return


Send,GYN:{SPACE}
Progress, m2 b fs14 zh0, Date of LMP, , , Arial
Inputbox, LMP, LMP 
Progress, Off
Sleep, 500

Send,LMP{SPACE}%LMP%,{SPACE}
Progress, m2 b fs14 zh0, Duration`ndays wks mo  , , , Arial
Inputbox, duration, Duration 
Progress, Off
Sleep, 500

Send, Duration{SPACE}%duration%,{SPACE}
Progress, m2 b fs14 zh0, G_/P_ `nPlease include letters G&P, , , Arial
Inputbox, gp, G_/P_ 
Progress, Off
Sleep, 500

Send,%gp%{SPACE}

gui, font, s14
gui, add, checkbox, w115 y15 virreg, Irregular
gui, add, checkbox, w115 vhflow, Heavy flow
gui, add, checkbox, w115 vndys, Dysmenorrhia
gui, add, checkbox, w115 y15 x+8 vreg, Regular
gui, add, checkbox, w150 y+9 vflow, Normal flow
gui, add, checkbox, w200 y+9 vdysmenorrhia, No Dysmenorrhia
gui, Add, button, x120 y130 gGyYN2, continue 
gui, Show, w400 h200, GYN
return


GYyN2:
gui, Submit
SEND,{space}
Sleep, 500

if irreg = 1
 {
  send, -{space}Irregular{space}
Progress, m2 b fs14 zh0, Further details of `nirregular flow, , , Arial
Inputbox, irf, Irregular flow details
Progress, Off
Sleep, 500
Send,%irf%

 }

if hflow = 1
 {
  send, -{SPACE}Heavy flow{space}
Progress, m2 b fs14 zh0, Further details of `nheavy flow, , , Arial
Inputbox, hfl, Heavy flow details
Progress, Off
Sleep, 500
Send,%hfl%
 }

if ndys = 1
 {
  send, -{space}Dysmenorrhia{space}
Progress, m2 b fs14 zh0, Further details of `ndysmenorrhia, , , Arial
Inputbox, dysmni, Dysmenorrhia details
Progress, Off
Sleep, 500
Send,%dysmni%
  - Normal flow- No Dysmenorrhia
 }

if reg = 1
 {
  send, -{space}Regular
 }  

if flow = 1
 {
  send, -{space}Normal flow
 }

if dysmenorrhia = 1
 {
  send, -{SPACE}No Dysmenorrhia

 }

 gui, destroy
```

Comment: Thank you Mat. If non = 1, I want it to skip everything below it and continue the rest of the script which would be: SEND, {ENTER} Send, Allergies:{SPACE} gui, font, s14 gui, add, checkbox, vNKDA, NKDA gui, add, checkbox, vproblist, See problem list gui, Add, button, gAllergies, continue gui, Show, w200 h150, Allergies return Allergies: gui, Submit SEND, {space} Sleep, 500 if NKDA = 1 { send, -{space}NKDA } if problist = 1 { send, -{space}See problem list } Gui, destroy send, {space} Progress, m2 b fs14 zh0, List other allergies or press Enter...

 How do i do that?